# Delete files and folders 1 level down

Tags: powershell, delete-file

I have some specific requirements for clearing out a shared folder. The shared folder is called "staff", below this are personal folders for each use (probably 60 in total), which get filled with crap.

I need to delete the crap (a mix of files and subfolders) within each users folder,  but preserve the user folder itself.

I also wish to exclude a few user folders based on name.

It currently looks like this:

```
\\fileserver\staff
   Bill
      Subfolder1
      Subfolder2
        File1
        File2
        File3
   Bob
      File1
      File2
      File3
   Brewster
      SubFolder1
          Subfolder2
          Subfolder3
            File1
   Brian
      Subfolder1
        File1
        File2
        File3
```

Assuming I want to exclude the user folders called "Bob" and "Brewster", the result would then look like

```
\\fileserver\staff
   Bill
      <empty>
   Bob
      FileA
      FileB
      FileC
   Brewster
      SubFolder1
        Subfolder2
          Subfolder3
            File1
   Brian
      <empty>
```

I have been trying `Get-Childitem` and `Remove-Item`, but can either get the `recurse` to work, or the `exclude` but not both. Also, I'm unsure how to specify to start after 1 level down from "Staff".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate the subfolders of `\\fileserver\staff` without recursion, excluding "Bob" and "Brewster", then enumerate the content of the remaining subfolders and recursively delete it.

```
Get-ChildItem '\\fileserver\staff' -Directory -Exclude 'Bob', 'Brewster' |
    Get-ChildItem -Force |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

Remove the parameter `-WhatIf` after you verified that the statement would only delete what it should.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much. Seems so easy when its put like that. I'm still learning Powershell so this will help me understand logic better. One point though, it did delete all the files in the users folders as expected, but left behind a "thumbs.db" in one of the folders. I understood "-Force" would delete hidden files, which this is.

Comment: As for the `thumbs.db` file: yes, normally `-Force` should delete those. Maybe something re-created it after deletion? I can't look into it right now, though. Maybe when I get home tonight.

Comment: Is the `thumbs.db` directly in one of the folders whose *content* you want deleted? If so, then you need to add `-Force` to `Get-ChildItem`, otherwise the file won't be listed and thus not deleted.